# MobileVLCKit fails while compiling

Tags: ios, vlc, rtsp, armv7, libvlc

I am trying to use MobileVLCKit for iOS in my application. I followed steps given @ [Building the Framework for iOS](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/). I have set deploymet target to iOS 7 in my Xcode 5.

I used command `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -f -l` to compile the shell file to get an iOS framework.

I got following errors on my terminal application.

```
The following build commands failed:
Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7
Libtool build/MobileVLCKit.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7s
CreateUniversalBinary build/Release-iphoneos/libMobileVLCKit.a normal armv7\ armv7s
```

I tried all ways got on google but it didn't work. After trying for whole day I am putting this question. Please help if you have used this before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Drop the -l argument. You really need to compile the underlying libvlc to achieve a full MobileVLCKit framework. Without libvlc, it's just a bunch of useless classes.

Alternatively, consider getting a precompiled version which can be just dropped in your project: http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/iOS/

Comment: Getting a precompiled version is really cool. I too searched for same but couldn't find it. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I downloaded the latest framework but it doesn't contain class VLCVideoView which is used in [Basic usage in your application](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/). How should I use it?

Comment: Check the sample code for iOS provided in the VLCKit git repository. VLCVideoView is an OS X only class. The same code path is handled slightly different on iOS.

Comment: Excellent, great to hear that!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am facing an issue while playing RTSP links. While playing the video audio starts before the pictures and I get the error 'Failed to resize the display' in log. Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: You can ignore the "Failed to resize the display" warning, since this is normal (you can't really adapt the output size on iOS the way you can on desktops).
Regarding video starting later than the audio, this depends on the availability of full frames to be displayed. Usually, those are being send at a regular interval, so this depends on your RTSP until the first full frame is ready for display.

Comment: Thanks. I just found that VLC player is requesting for UDP connection first and then TCP. I need to avoid that and force it to stream over TCP. I found a flag **--rtsp-tcp** on searching. But how should I use it? I tried setting `[objVlcplayer.media addOptions:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"--rtsp-tcp"]]` but that doesn't work.Sorry this may be basic but I am new to this framework and couldn't find much help at other places so have to come to you only.

Comment: Most likely, this option is not supported by the VLCMedia object, but needs to be set globally on the VLCMediaPlayer object on its initialization.

Comment: Ok but no such function found available on VLCMediaPlayer

Comment: Can you please specify such function which will force the player to play the stream over TCP? I got this function in VLCMedia class. Couldn't find anything in VLCMediaPlayer class :(

Comment: You need to add this option to [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:@[…]] …

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Comment: Now i can able to download the pre compiled version from this site http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/ios/

Can anyone please share that it is relay helpful for me thanks in advance

Comment: When I build for iOS real device I get same error Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_openat", referenced from:
      _vlc_openat in MobileVLCKit(lt4-filesystem.o) In emulator it works fine!!!