# MobileVLCKit not compiling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, flv

I am trying to compile MobileVLCKit based on instructions in this page:

```
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/
```

When I run `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh` It start doing some thing and the download about 200 MB and finally shows below error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/MobileVLCKit.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/VLCLibrary.o Sources/VLCLibrary.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I checked the iOS sample but still it has not working.

I also tried to build it with `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -s`but I see below error:

```
    The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/MobileVLCKit.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MobileVLCKit.build/Objects-normal/i386/VLCLibrary.o Sources/VLCLibrary.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I also see this post:

[MobileVLCKit fails while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728328/mobilevlckit-fails-while-compiling)

and checked the url for the precompiled sources at here:

http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/iOS/

but actually I am not any idea on how can I use them. Even I do not know I should download witch of them?!!

Does some body any idea on what is the problem with building this library or how to use this precompiled files.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if answer is needed still for that but I'll answer this for future generations and lost souls.

So the short answer is: mobileVLCkit should compile if you have xcode installed. If it does not compile then that means that the current version on git is broken. That happens more often then you think.

At the mentioned link http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/iOS/ you can download nightly builds of mobileVLCkit. Those builds will work on both hardware and simulator. They are prepared every night as long as the latest code compiles so you can download the latest version. You can often see that those builds are week or more behind git. That means that git code does not compile :) Personally I believe there is hardly any reason to build this lib yourself. Just grab a nightly.

Now to clear the confusion mobile vlc kit is only a C library + required header files. You are not going to get any cool control to place in a view with buttons and such. You need to hand craft all of that.

Comment: Are there other frameworks that we need to add in addition to the MobileVLCKit.framework? The project doesn't compile when just dropping a nightly build / framework in and adding "#import <MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h>" ... there appears to be lots of linker errors.

Comment: Update: what I ended up doing was cloning the iOS repo via the instructions here: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/ . I then opened one of the iOS examples within the directory that comes down from the clone. Next, I manually added a nightly to the project (as described in answer above). That still didn't work, so I deleted the .a reference in the project to the MobileVLCKit library. That got the project running. That all took me about a day or so to figure out.

Comment: How do the nightlies work.  They are listed as a .zip file, but neither my windows PC nor my mac could unzip them.  Is the file extension incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.i tried like this
Go to build settings > enable bitcode > Choose "NO". It is working fine now. If you face the same issue please give it a try. Hope your issue gets resolved.

Thanks!